# What is the difference between memetic algorithms and genetic algorithms?

Tags: comparison, terminology, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-computation

What is the difference between [memetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetic_algorithm) and [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)? Is an individual's lifetime a learning part of memetic algorithms?

Answer (score 6):

A genetic algorithm is an algorithm, based on natural selection (the process that drives biological evolution), for solving both constrained and unconstrained optimization problems.

A memetic algorithm is an extension of the concept of a genetic algorithm that uses a local search technique to reduce the likelihood of premature convergence.

The paper [A Comparison between Memetic algorithm and Genetic algorithm for the cryptanalysis of Simplified Data Encryption Standard algorithm](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1004/1004.0574.pdf) compares both approaches.

To answer your last question, yes, an individual's lifetime still plays a part in memetic algorithms because the objective here is to avoid premature convergence.